# New to Fusion: Is there a need to enhance virus protection

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, vmware-fusion

I'm a new user to Fusion, just bought Fusion 3. I intend to install on my iMac and then run Windows 7. I've always enjoyed the freedom of not worrying much about viruses with the Mac. Now that I'm going to add the Windows op system though, I am concerned I might need to change that mindset. Anyone who can share expertise/input on this is much appreciated. Thx. 
SLH

Answer (score 1):

You can take snapshots and then not be so worried of malware, however, you will be just as vulnerable to malware on a virtual machine as you would on a physical - feel free to install AV if you wish (I recommend [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/) if you do), but if you are careful and use UAC wisely, you may not need any AV at all.